# Syncing postgres database between client and server

Tags: database, postgresql, replication

I need to syncronize two postgres databases running on Windows. They must be identical.

In one side, i have a windows app with a local postgres database. On the other side i have a .NET web application on  Windows Server 2012 with a postgres database.

Frequently the Windows side works offline, i need to syncronize the two databases when the windows side come online.

What approach should i use? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both sides update the database? There is no easy way to do it. One way people solve this problem is by having a version number on every row. Every change increases the version. Then you "only" have to solve the collission problem, if both sides happened to change the same row.

Comment: Yeap. The ideal is both sides syncing but for now i´ll be happy just with Windows to Web syncing.
Is there any postgres replication scenario ( for windows ) that solves my problem?

Comment: Two-way asynchronous multi-master is a *hard* problem because both nodes can change the data in ways that conflict when they try to sync. You should really sync in one direction only, with one database read-only. Otherwise you have a *lot* more work ahead of you to understand asynchronous multi-master replication, conflict handling, etc. For one-way sync, something like Londiste, Bucardo, etc should be fine.

Comment: Those solutions are for unix-based systems only, right? On both sides i run .NET solutions.

One way synchronization would work fine for me, but the neither sides can be read-only.

I need a solution where both my databases should be identical, one side ( customer ) running a local database with a desktop app and in the other ( Web app ) running antoher database on ther server that receives ( and modify ) data from the customers databases.

In the worst case scenario the customers databases can contain only their info and the server database the consolidated info from all customers.

Comment: There is likely no out-of-the-box solution for your problem.